# Form is presenting same data in php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get an edit form to work with the loop in the php. I have a delete button and it works just fine. The edit form keeps presenting only the first row in the table. In firebug, it shows that all the other forms are there with the correct unique id for each but only the first form shows when edit is clicked on different rows. Can someone help me as to why?

```
<table id="table_id" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID #</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_sql)) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td id = "clicked"><?=$row['ID']?></td>
            <td id = "clicked"><?=$row['Product']?></td>
            <td id = "clicked"><?=$row['Quantity']?></td>
            <td id = "clicked">$ <?=$row['Price']?></td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="div_show2(this, '<?=$row['ID']?>'); return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Edit</button>
              <!-- Modal for the Edit Data Form -->
              <div id ="hidden-form2">
              <div id = "popupContact">
              <form action= "updateData.php" id = "editForm<?=$row['ID']?>" method="POST" name="editForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?=$row['ID']?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="product">Product</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product<?=$row['ID']?>" name="product" value="<?=$row['Product']?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">  
                  <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity<?=$row['ID']?>" name="quantity" value="<?=$row['Quantity']?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="price">Price</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price<?=$row['ID']?>" name="price" value="<?=$row['Price']?>">
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="formHide2()">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </form>
              </div>
              </div>
              <!--End of Edit Form-->
            </td>
            <td> 
              <!--Delete Button Form-->
              <form method="post" action="deleteData.php">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button> 
              <input type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" value="<?=$row['ID']?>">
              </form>      
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
    }
        ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

//script for calling the edit forms as a modal popup
//Function To Display Popup for Edit form

```
function div_show2() {
document.getElementById("editForm").reset(); 
document.getElementById('hidden-form2').style.display = "block";
}

//Function to Hide Popup
function formHide2(){ 
document.getElementById('hidden-form2').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: I would like to see the `script` for calling `<div id ="hidden-form2">`

Comment: *Again Asking*. Please post your script for calling `<div id ="hidden-form2">` I'm having Idea to fix that issue. But, I would like to see that script first.

Comment: @NanaPartykar already posted it.

Comment: Just update your question to include your scripts as well. I've been asking to see the `show_div2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `show_div2` function is only showing one element.

```
document.getElementById('hidden-form2').style.display = "block";
```

That shows you why you are only seeing the first row.

Update your HTML and Javascript as follows

#### HTML

```
<div id="hidden-form2<?=$row['ID']?>">
```

#### Javascript

```
function div_show2(id) {
    document.getElementById("editForm"+id).reset(); 
    document.getElementById('hidden-form2'+id).style.display = "block";
}
```

To avoid having any problems like this in the future, always make sure that your id's are unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did it right here. I was making the form id's unique and not the outer div. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: Glad to help. Always remind yourself that whenever you are inside a loop, check that the `id` you set on elements inside the loop is unique.

Answer (score 1):

The first 4 `td` I see all use the same `id` name `clicked`. Try to fix that first and see what happens.

```
<td class="clicked" id="clickedID<?=$row['ID']?>"><?=$row['ID']?></td>
<td class="clicked" id="clickedProduct<?=$row['ID']?>"><?=$row['Product']?></td>
<td class="clicked" id="clickedQuantity<?=$row['ID']?>"><?=$row['Quantity']?></td>
<td class="clicked" id="clickedPrice<?=$row['ID']?>">$ <?=$row['Price']?></td>
```

Comment: Nothing changes when i make them unique id. I have also tried the form out of the loop and that still produce the same results. Only first row forms shows no matter which row you click.